# Merging 2 label values into one with seperator /

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, machine-learning, data-structures

I have a medical dataset as follows :

```
subject_id  value   valueuom    label   storetime   charttime
46907   41976   73.000000   bpm Heart Rate  1945-09-09 07:45:36.251539968   1993-05-12 20:18:40.247972992
45865   44262   85.895129   bpm Heart Rate  1982-07-18 00:29:09.684835072   1980-01-21 15:54:35.219542912
20199   40595   33.000000   insp/min    Respiratory Rate    2011-02-11 16:37:45.403357952   2011-10-01 12:15:19.696008960
47874   41976   107.000000  bpm Heart Rate  1908-12-22 01:42:59.887796992   1941-08-03 19:16:32.122537984
1218    10061   111.000000  BPM Heart Rate  1956-03-24 03:46:02.217875968   1945-02-25 03:53:00.807330944
```

I have multiple class labels, where I have 2 labels that denote the measurement of heart rates : *Non-Invasive Blood Pressure systolic & Non-Invasive Blood Pressure diastolic*. I need to combine the values for these 2 labels as one in the entire dataset and use a separator /  for example :

```
46907 / 47801 73.0000 / 84.0000  Non Invasive Blood Pressure systolic / Non Invasive Blood Pressure diastolic and so on in the dataset
```

I was trying to use join for this or pd.merge( ) by constructing two separate Dataframes one for each label and then join them with a seperator but it doesn't seems to provide a working solution.

If anyone can suggest on this it would be great!

Comment: Your sample data does not include either 47801 or 84.0000.  Is there another table?  How will you join then?

Comment: no its just an example which I created , I have a very huge dataset , by joining I meant I tried to create 2 separate dataframes containing only values for one of the label and then doing join

Comment: Could you please provide a sample df and expected output to reproduce. as 47801 or 84.0000 is missing.